# Changing cache size for geocoding via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, cache

I recently posted this query: [Arcpy script stalls, CPU usage goes to 0, no error message returned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221868/arcpy-script-stalls-cpu-usage-goes-to-0-no-error-message-returned) and got as a suggestion to increase the cache size in Arcpy for the geocoding of addresses that I am performing.

The link [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geocoding/locator-performance-properties.htm) describes how to do this for the GUI version of ArcMap.

But, the [support page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geocoding/geocode-addresses.htm) for the `GeocodeAddresses_geocoding` doesn't mention how to manage the cache via Arcpy, nor can I find other references to it.

How can this be accomplished in Arcpy?

Comment: This [comment](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/57348) is fairly old, but still applies to the best of my (non-expert) knowledge of locators

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KHibma:

> This [comment](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/57348) is fairly old,
>   but still applies to the best of my (non-expert) knowledge of locators

The comment linked to is by Bruce Harold of Esri:

> There are no ArcPy methods for accessing the runtime properties of a
>   locator. An approach you may want to look at is making a copy of the
>   locator with different properties.